# Connection reset by peer error in MongoDb on bulk insert

Tags: bulkinsert, pymongo

I am trying to insert 500 documents by doing a bulk insert in pymongo and i get this error

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 306, in insert
    continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 748, in _send_message
    raise AutoReconnect(str(e))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

i looked around and found [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mongodb.user/3606) that this happens because the size of inserted documents exceeds 16 MB so according to that the size of 500 documents should be over 16 MB. So i checked the size of the size of the 500 documents(python dictionaries) like this

```
size=0
for dict in dicts:
    size+=dict.__sizeof__()
print size
```

this gives me `502920`. This is like 500 KB. way less than 16 MB. Then why do i get this error.
I know i am calculating the size of python dictionaries not BSON documents and MongoDB takes in BSON documents but that cant turn 500KB into 16+ MB. Moreover i dont know how to convert a python dict into A BSON document.

My MongoDB version is 2.0.6 and pymongo version is 2.2.1

**EDIT**
I can do a bulk insert with 150 documents and thats fine but over 150 documents this error appears

Comment: [This bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-414) has been fixed.  If you're still experiencing issues, please update **pymongo**.

Answer (score 1):

This [Bulk Inserts bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-414) has been resolved, but you may need to update your pymongo version:

`pip install --upgrade pymongo`

Answer (score 0):

> The error occurs due to the fact that the bulk inserted documents have
>   an overall size of greater than 16 MB

```
My method of calculating the size of dictionaries was wrong.
```

When i manually inspected each key of the dictionary and found that 1 key was having a value of size 300 KB. So that did make the overall size of documents in the bulk insert more than 16 MB. `(500*(300+)KB) > 16 MB`. But i still dont know how to calculate size of a dictionary without manually inspecting it. Can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same error and got around it by creating my own small bulks like this:

```python
region_list = []
region_counter = 0
write_buffer = 1000
# loop through regions
for region in source_db.region.find({}, region_column):
    region_counter += 1 # up _counter
    region_list.append(region)
    # save bulk if we're at the write buffer
    if region_counter == write_buffer:
        result = user_db.region.insert(region_list)
        region_list = []
        region_counter = 0
# if there is a rest, also save that
if region_counter > 0:
    result = user_db.region.insert(region_list)
```

Hope this helps

NB: small update, from pymongo 2.6 on, PyMongo will auto-split lists based on the max transfer size: "The insert() method automatically splits large batches of documents into multiple insert messages based on max_message_size"